# Trello banner saying : "You are almost out of backup verification codes." - what does it mean?

Tags: trello

Ive logged into Trello.com this morning and there is a yellow banner across the top saying :

You are almost out of backup verification codes. **Generate new backup codes.**

(see below screenshot)

The generate new backup codes is a link that when clicked on asks me to log into trello .. even though im already logged in and able to access my boards ?

Any ideas what this is ?

[image: trello screenshot]

Comment: Also seeing this, have tweeted 'em to find out but suspecting either a bug or someone attempting to login to my account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trello Support says this happens if you have 2FA enabled but have never generated any recovery codes, which is the case for me:

https://twitter.com/trellosupport/status/771466148697210880

Unsure what triggered the warning though, since I have had an account for a good long while now with 2FA enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate backup codes for 2FA, hope that helps!

Comment: This is a correct answer, not sure why it was downvoted twice.., i have added 1 up vote. I have marked the other answer as accepted as it was more detailed.